# PDFbox Preflight PDF/A-1b check not working properly in java version 1.8

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdfa

I am using PDFBOX Preflight to validate pdf document to check whether it is in PDF/A-1b format or not . It works perfectly on java 1.7 but when I run the code in java 1.8 i get following errors

2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing

2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing

2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing

7.11 : Error on MetaData

I am using pdfbox 1.8.8 and preflight 1.8.3

Following is the code that I am using for validating the PDFs doing this.

```
                ValidationResult result = null;
                FileDataSource fd = new FileDataSource(InputFolder
                        + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                PreflightParser parser = new PreflightParser(fd);
                try {
                    parser.parse(Format.PDF_A1A);
                    PreflightDocument documentt = parser
                            .getPreflightDocument();
                    documentt.validate();
                    result = documentt.getResult();
                    documentt.close();
                } catch (SyntaxValidationException e) {
                    result = e.getResult();
                }
                if (result.isValid()) {
                    System.out
                            .println("The file  is a valid PDF/A-1a file");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("The file is not valid, error(s) :");

                            for (ValidationError error : result
                                    .getErrorsList()) {
                                message = error.getErrorCode() + " : "
                                        + error.getDetails();
                                fos.write(message.getBytes());
                                fos.write(System.getProperty(
                                        "line.separator").getBytes());
                                // System.out.println(error.getErrorCode() +
                                // " : " + error.getDetails());
                            }

}
```

Is PDFBOX not compatible with java 1.8 or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: This is probably the type of question that is better asked on the user mailing list or on JIRA, as it will probably require a lot of back and forth. However make sure that 1) you're using the same version, 2) the file is available for evaluation. You can also check the file with http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx . Good luck!

Comment: @tilman do you mind if I ask you a few questions here .... or should I ask a new question .

Comment: It depends whether it is about THIS topic. For new topics you should open a new question (the idea is that your questions should help users in the future). But you should really do the things I mentioned in my first comment, i.e. 1) using same version of pdfbox and preflight, 2) test your file with PDF Tools. 3) Make the file available.

Comment: @tilman your advice worked . I was actually using different versions of preflight.jar and pdfbox jar . I then used 1.8.8 version of both and Its working . I think we should put this comment as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As solved in the comments: always use the same version of the PDFBox and the Preflight jar files, which is 1.8.8 at the time this response is written.

Additional bonus advice: when getting results that you don't believe, get a "2nd opinion" with the [free PDF-Tools PDF/A-1b validator](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx).

If the results are different, open an issue in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX) or try the [2.0 snapshots of PDFBox + preflight](https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/):