# how to validate all preflight error for PDF/A-1a in pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

i am working with vaildate PDFA/1A .I followed this code which already exist in this link [PDFbox Preflight PDF/A-1b check not working properly in java version 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112318/pdfbox-preflight-pdf-a-1b-check-not-working-properly-in-java-version-1-8)

```
public class test
{
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    File pdfa=new File("D:/DMC-B787-A-00-40-07-00A-008B-D.pdf"); // error pdf
    isPDFAdocument(pdfa);
    System.out.println("sucess");
  }

  private static void isPDFAdocument(File pdfa) 
  {
    ValidationResult result = null;

    PreflightParser parser;
    try
    {
      parser = new PreflightParser(pdfa);

      parser.parse(Format.PDF_A1A);
      PreflightDocument documentt = parser.getPreflightDocument();
      result = documentt.getResult();
      System.out.println("result"+result);
      documentt.close();

    }
    catch (SyntaxValidationException e)
    {
      result = e.getResult();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (result.isValid())
    {
      System.out.println("The file " + pdfa + " is a valid PDF/A-1a file");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("The file" + pdfa + " is not valid, error(s) :");
      for (ValidationError error : result.getErrorsList())
      {
        System.out.println(error.getErrorCode() + " : " + error.getDetails());
      }
    }
```

it's not checking the error which mention below .if there it have to show exception but still its vaildate success.
Kindly suggest how to validate all probability preflight error below .how to check it in pdfbox.

**Error**

```
CharSet incomplete for Type 1 font (2 matches on 1 page) - 2
Width information for rendered glyphs is inconsistent (2 matches on 1 page) - 2
Document information
File name: "DMC-B787-A-00-40-07-00A-008B-D.pdf"
Path: "C:\Users\wm751e\Documents\Feb19\Synchronize print\Only WDM\Archived doctypes
latest\EA_TBC2016-02-2115.57.49IPD\EA_TBC2016-02-2115.57.49IPD\00"
PDF version number: "1.4"
File size (KB): 114.2
Title: "Illustrated Parts Data - Service Bulletin/Modification List"
Author: "The Boeing Company (PRINTENGINEWEB_BUILD_1.7.49.5.0.0; s1000d_merged_v6.5.36_4.xsl; JobID:)"
Creator: "AH XSL Formatter V6.0 MR7 for Linux64 : 6.0.8.9416 (2013/02/26 10:36JST)"
Producer: "Antenna House PDF Output Library 6.0.389 (Linux64)"
Created: "2/21/2016 3:56 PM"
Modified: "2/21/2016 3:56 PM"
Trapping: "False"
Number of plates: 4
Names of plates: "(Cyan) (Magenta) (Yellow) (Black) "
Environment
Preflight, 15.0.0 (151)
Acrobat version: 15.60
Operating system: Microsoft Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (Build 7601
```

Comment: *suggest how to validate all probability preflight error* - implement missing tests when you recognize the need and share them with the community.

Comment: when we verify compliance with pdfa/1a preflight the manually the error occurs           updated the error ..@MKI

Comment: Please retest your file with the 2.0 version of preflight: https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x  That one has better font support. If it still doesn't work properly, please share your file.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr when i used the jar preflight-2.0.0-RC3.jar and pdfbox-2.0.0-RC3.jar am getting error like 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.<init>(Lorg/apache/pdfbox/io/RandomAccessRead;)V
 at org.apache.pdfbox.preflight.parser.PreflightParser.<init>(PreflightParser.java:109)'

Comment: @SenthilKumar you probably still have an old version of pdfbox*jar in your class path. Try the preflight-app instead, which has all. (it also works as command line)

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr thx for reply but again it failed from latest jar also .its not capturing the error while parsing and load

Comment: @SenthilKumar "it success from latest jar also" - does this mean your problem has been solved? This contradicts the words "but again" which suggests failure.

Comment: sry its again not validated the error its failed again can i have emaild id to send files

Comment: You can use the address mentioned in my profile, so I can share it publicly. Alternatively create an issue in the [PDFBox Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX) and attach the PDF.

Comment: thx for reply.. PreflightDocument documentt = parser.getPreflightDocument(); after this i added the documentt.validate now its showing the list of error ..but it's not throw any exception how  to handle some exception??

Comment: My address is tilman at snafu dot de. Don't send anything bigger than 1 MB - if it is bigger, upload it to a sharehoster instead. Mention what level of confidentiality you want. If parsing throws an exception then it means the file is really to "rotten" to check. If there is no exception, then look at the result object.